# Javascript code not displaying wanted output

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, activex

I've written some code to display my favorites in IE8 but for an unknown reason I have no output on the screen despite the fact that my page is accepted by IE and that the test text 'this is a test' is displayed.

my code :

```
<html>
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso 8859-1" />

   <script type="text/javascript">
        var i = 0;
        var favString = "";
        var fso;

        function GetFavourites(Folder) {
            var FavFolder = fso.GetFolder(Folder);
            //Gets Favourite Names & URL's for given folder.
            var files = new Enumerator(FavFolder.Files);
            for (; !files.atEnd(); files.moveNext()) {
                var fil = files.item();
                if (fil.Type == "Internet Shortcut") {
                    var textReader = fso.OpenTextFile(fil.Path, 1, false, -2);
                    var favtext = textReader.ReadAll();
                    var start = favtext.indexOf("URL", 16);
                    var stop = favtext.indexOf("\n", start);
                    favString += fil.Name.replace(/.url/, "");
                    favString += ":URL:";
                    //to separate favourite name & favorite URL
                    favString += favtext.substring(start + 4, stop - 1);
                    favorites.innerHTML += favString; // Not working !
                    favorites.innerHTML += 'test'; // Not working too !
                    favString += ":NEXT:"; //to separate favorites.
                    i++;
                }
            }
            //Checks any subfolder exists
            var subfolders = new Enumerator(FavFolder.SubFolders);
            for (; !subfolders.atEnd(); subfolders.moveNext()) {
                var folder = subfolders.item();
                GetFavourites(folder.Path);
            }
        }

        function Import() {
            try {
                fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
                if (fso !== null) {
                    //Create windows script shell object to access Favorites folder in user system.
                    var object = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
                    var favfolderName = object.SpecialFolders("Favorites");
                    if (favString === "") {
                        GetFavourites(favfolderName);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (err) {
                alert("Security settings to be modified in your browser ");
            }
        }
   </script>

   </head>

   <body onload="Import()">

      <p>this is a test</p>     <!-- Working ! -->

      <div id="favorites">
      </div>
   </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I would expect this script to be blocked by security settings.

Comment: @Hogan Yes the script is blocked by IE and needs the user permission to work.

Comment: Stepping through your code line-by-line, it worked for me.  Are you getting any error messages in IE8's developer tools (F12)?

Comment: @Andy E No I have no error messages in the developer tools. When you say it's working for you do you mean your favorites appear on the page ?

Comment: @Bruno: kind of.  I don't have those kinds of security settings enabled for the browser, but I have a desktop gadget (running on IE 8) with a console.  I stepped through the code but changed the output, pushing the results to an array rather than a DOM element.  The rest of the code stayed the same, though, and it worked fine.

Comment: @Andy E Can you please post your code ? I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: @Bruno: done.  If you're still having problems with it let me know and I might be able to offer more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
var fso, favs = [];
function GetFavourites(Folder) {
    var FavFolder = fso.GetFolder(Folder);
    //Gets Favourite Names & URL's for given folder.
    var files = new Enumerator(FavFolder.Files);
    for (; !files.atEnd(); files.moveNext()) {
        var fil = files.item();
        if (fil.Type == "Internet Shortcut") {
            var textReader = fso.OpenTextFile(fil.Path, 1, false, -2);
            var favtext = textReader.ReadAll();
            var start = favtext.indexOf("URL", 16);
            var stop = favtext.indexOf("\n", start);
            favString = fil.Name.replace(/.url/, "");
            favString += ":URL:";
            //to separate favourite name & favorite URL
            favString += favtext.substring(start + 4, stop - 1);
            favs.push(favString);
        }
    }
    //Checks any subfolder exists
    var subfolders = new Enumerator(FavFolder.SubFolders);
    for (; !subfolders.atEnd(); subfolders.moveNext()) {
        var folder = subfolders.item();
        GetFavourites(folder.Path);
    }
}
function Import() {
    try {
        fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        if (fso !== null) {
            //Create windows script shell object to access Favorites folder in user system.
            var object = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
            var favfolderName = object.SpecialFolders("Favorites");
            if (favString === "") {
                GetFavourites(favfolderName);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert("Security settings to be modified in your browser ");
    }
}
```

Note that all I changed was the output from an element to an array named `favs`.  I also removed the `i` variable, because it wasn't used.  After running the script, I checked the array in the developer tools console and it contained all my favourites.

Comment: @Andy E Thanks a lot for your answer ! I'm still new at developing on IE, how do I check the array in the dev tools please ? It doesn't appear in the local variables.

Comment: @Bruno: go to the console/script tab and type the name of the variable (`favs`) into the console window.  You could also type `JSON.stringify(favs)` to get it in JSON format.

Comment: @Andy E Done but nothing happens. Is this a normal behaviour ? :-)

Comment: @Bruno: it just fills the array, if there's nothing in the array then it probably didn't work.  I don't use the IE 8 console, so it could be a little different from mine (a custom one), so you could try dumping the array to the body - `document.body.innerText = JSON.stringify(favs, null, 4);`

Comment: @Bruno: then I'm not sure what I can do to help, sorry!

Comment: @Andy E You've already done a lot, thanks ! As soon as I find an answer I'll post it.

Comment: @Andy I have now access to favs but the array is empty {...}.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting no output at all, then either `fso` is null in the `Import` method or `files.AtEnd()` always evaluates to false. Since you're focusing on IE here, you might consider placing alert methods in various places with values to debug (such as `alert(fso);`) throughout your expected code path.