# Onload event not working with Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, onload

I've written some very simple code on Internet Explorer 8 and I don't understand why nothing happens when I open the page with IE (why the text 'test' doesn't appear on the page).

I've tried on Firefox and Chrome and it works perfectly.

my code :

```
<html>
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso 8859-1" />

   <script type="text/javascript">

   function display() {
      output.innerHTML+='test';
   }

   </script>

   </head>

   <body onload="display()">

      <div id="output">
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Edit : let IE change your setting, don't do it by hand or it gets weird :-))

Comment: As mentioned in the answers already, `document.getElementById` is the usual method of getting a handle on an element from the document.  Does this work for you; http://jsbin.com/uqama4? It works for me on Vista/IE 8

Comment: I would re-install IE 8, or upgrade to IE 9.

Comment: Works fine in IE8 for me. Have you turned JS off in your installation of IE or something?

Comment: one thing that pops in my mind is active x is not enabled or JS disabled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += 'test';
```

Comment: Internet Explorer and some other browsers automatically register elements as global variables using `id` as the variable name, so I can't see this fixing the problem.

Comment: @Andy E You're right it doesn't change anything. By the way I think we're touching the element that is the core of the problem of my previous post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962647/javascript-code-not-displaying-wanted-output):-).

Comment: If you can't rely on it in all browsers, it's not a good solution. document.getElementById() is the correct way to do it. Even better, use jQuery i.e. $('#output').html('test');

Comment: @James: it doesn't make any difference, the post is tagged `internet-explorer`, and the code in the OP's previous question will only work in IE anyway (because it makes use of activex).

Comment: Weird. I copied your HTML directly into a new file and your code works fine in IE8 in both Quirks and IE8 mode.

Comment: @James McCormack You're right. IE was doing some weird stuff on his own.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
   function display() {
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML+='test';
   }
```

Comment: @Bruno did you allow block content when accessing the html?  Make sure Active-X is enabled.